# Drawing by one click on Leaflet

Tags: android, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in Android so I want to draw polygon by **one click** because it is too hard to

draw by clicking two times to the same point on tablet.

I'm using Leaflet.draw plugin and this [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/) is working on browser perfectly and you can draw polygon on browser by one click.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/

But if I use the same demo on android, I have to click two times on the same point for drawing polygon.

This is not user friendly.

How can i do that ?

**Note :** I shared piece of code on below about drawing polygon. I tested it on browser and mobile.

Eventually, I have to click twice on mobile device for drawing polygon unlike browser.

**This is draw control**

```
drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
                        draw : {
                            position : 'topleft',
                            polygon : {
                                title : 'Draw a polygon',
                                allowIntersection : false,
                                drawError : {
                                    color : '#b00b00',
                                    timeout : 1000
                                },
                                shapeOptions : {
                                    color : '#bada55'
                                },
                                showArea : true
                            },
                            polyline : false,
                            rectangle : false,
                            circle : false,
                            marker : false
                        },
                        edit : {
                            featureGroup : drawnItems
                        }
                    });
                    map.addControl(drawControl);
```

**This is created event**

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
                console.log("created");
        //This is created event which is triggered after polygon creation
                           });
```

Comment: I really don't understand why people giving negative point to my question ? 
It is clear question and don't need any piece of code.

Comment: I think you should write what you tried and what was the result ? Then ask more specific question to get an answer.

Comment: Updated. Is it enough or not ?

Comment: Wow, you were able to get it to draw AT ALL? It works perfectly in a browser on my laptop, but on my iPad, it doesn't work at all. I can select the tool (point/polyline/polygon etc) but I can't even draw the first point. Every once in awhile, I can finally get the first point, but it usually is no where near where I was trying to get it.